# Odoo: Encoding won't work if different layout is called

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

so I inherited "report_pricelist" in order to change the basic layout to the external layout:

```
<template id="product.report_pricelist">
    <t t-call="web.external_layout">
    <main>
        <div class="page">
            <t t-call="product.report_pricelist_page"/>
        </div>
        <p style="page-break-before:always;"> </p>
    </main>
    </t>
</template>
```

This results in the report not encoding correctly, euro-symbol garbled etc..

If I change "external_layout" to "basic_layout", the encoding works again.

How can I use the external layout and also get the correct encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem got on my nerves for weeks, and 15 min after posting this question I now found the solution:

```
<template id="product.report_pricelist">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-call="web.external_layout">
        <main>
            <div class="page">
                <t t-call="product.report_pricelist_page"/>
            </div>
            <p style="page-break-before:always;"> </p>
        </main>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

It needs to be wrapped in a web.html_container. Now it encodes correctly. Don't ask me why that makes the difference..